# join another table with if statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join, conditional-statements

I want to join another table if a `field` of current table equals to some specific value.
For example :  ( this is not mysql syntax )

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ( IF products.is_package IS NOT NULL THEN INNER JOIN `packages` )
```

Table products:

```
 +----+-----------+
 | id | is_package|
 +----+-----------+
 | 1  |   1       | // which joins package with id 1
 +----+-----------+
 | 2  | NULL      |
 +----+-----------+
 | 3  |   2       | // which joins package with id 2
 +----+-----------+
```

Is it possible to do this in mysql?

Comment: Isn't this just a left join?

Comment: is it? I am new to sql languages

Comment: it is just a left join

Comment: I want to have data in both cases, whether is_package is null or is id. does left join works for this purpose ?

Comment: Yes left join will return all records from the primary table, records that fail the secondary join will be null.

Comment: It's a straight forward `LEFT JOIN` as long as your `PACKAGES` table does **not** have corresponding records for `PRODUCTS` with `products.is_package` as `NULL`.

Comment: what if is_package conitains ENUM values. foreach ENUM , joining a specific table. how can I do that

Comment: If you know all `ENUM` **values** and corresponding **foreign keys** in advance, then you will join them all but use `CASE WHEN` construct to retrieve exactly what you need.  And it still will be a bunch of `LEFT JOIN`s. It will not be pretty but should be doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if condition you can just put it in WHERE clause .try this

```
  SELECT * FROM `products` LEFT JOIN `packages` 
  ON your_clause_here
```

Comment: I want to have data in both cases, whether is_package is null or is id. does left join works for this purpose ?

Comment: what if is_package conitains ENUM values. foreach ENUM , joining a specific table. how can I do that

Comment: @Pars - I addressed *ENUM* situation in my comment under your main post.

Answer (score 3):

```
 SELECT * FROM `products` LEFT JOIN `packages` 
  ON products.is_package = packages.id
```